# if ("i am on this html page") { play this music};

Tags: javascript, html

```
if ("I am on this html page") {play this music};
```

Are there any commands to make this possible using Javascript?

this code worked for me :)

```js
var soundEfx2 = document.getElementById("soundEfx2");
var soundMain = "Music/Main.mp3";
if(window.location.href.split('/').pop() == "Game2.html") {
    soundEfx2.src = soundMain;
    soundEfx2.play();
    soundEfx2.loop = true;
}
```

Comment: use window.location.href

Comment: To make what ? Play music or check the page?

Comment: Try witth `if(window.location.href.split('/').pop() == "Game2.html"){...}`

Comment: What if the sound is off or the user doesn't have speakers?

Comment: @Tim then they just cant heer thesounds, music, thats all...

Comment: OK - I wanted to make sure it wasn't critical to what you're doing.

Comment: @Vucko what am i supposed to fill in the ('/')?

Comment: @elvinl. literally type `('/')`. A URL looks like this: `site.com/folder/place/page.html`. @Vucko's code makes it so you compare just the `page.html` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your URL is `http://foo.com/bar.html`.

With `window.location.href` you're getting the whole URL (`http://foo.com/bar.html`), but you only need to get the last URL *segment* (`bar.html`) of that URL, so use:

```
if(window.location.href.split('/').pop() == "Game2.html"){
    // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location.href=='THIS_URL'){
 //play the song
}
```

you can play it via jquery by getting the player id and calling the appropriate function and you can render the player by opening the php tags and echoing the PLAYER code.

Comment: I just gave you an idea.. it was not the exact code that you wanted

Comment: if (window.location.href == "Game2.html")
    {
    soundEfx2.src = soundMain;
    soundEfx2.play();
    soundEfx2.loop = true;
    }

Comment: @elvinl. that seemed to be the type.. you inserted ; after }

Comment: @elvinl. just modified your question..copy and paste that code and try

Comment: the player works; cus if i just do this in my js:                                 soundEfx2.src = soundMain;
    soundEfx2.play();
    soundEfx2.loop = true; it works, problem is that i need it in an if statement to work

Comment: @elvinl. Also, you need to know that `window.location.href` will return the full URL, so comparing it to "Game2.html" probably won't work.

Comment: I see, well  at least we know the problem of if(window.location.href=='THIS_URL'){
 //play the song
}  the:  if(window.location.href.split('/').pop() == "Game2.html") works with witout full url  :)

Comment: It was just to give you an idea..you were comparing the ending part of the page with url.